# I am studying fragmentation warheads and this formula of 'numbers of fragments hitting the target' is just not making sense

Tags: statistics

What is parameter 'p' in the formula? If somebody knows any better source to study this part... welcome to suggest. Thanks a lot.

> Probable Number of Fragments Hitting the Target
>
> It can be proven that the fragments from a typical warhead are generally lethal at long range, far in excess of the lethal effects from blast weapons of equivalent size. Drag reduces the energy slowly. For example, fragments from a hand-grenade can be dangerous to a range of about 100 m. However, the likelihood of being struck by a fragment at 100 m is small. There are only so many fragments that are distributed in all directions. The average number striking a target will reduce proportionally to 1/R^2, where R is the range. We can express this in the following formula:
>
> N_hits = A(N_o/4pR^2)
>
> where:
>
> N_hits is the expected number of fragments hitting the target;
>
> N_o is the initial number of fragments from the warhead;
>
> A is the frontal area of the target presented to the warhead; and
>
> R is the range of the target to the warhead.

You can follow the link and search for  'fragments hitting the target' here https://fas.org/man/dod-101/navy/docs/es310/dam_crit/dam_crit.htm

Comment: Hi Ad Sinc, it's against our rules to post images of text you want to quote. Please type it out instead so it can be indexed by search engines. For formulas, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $p$ is a crude stand-in for $\pi$. The site probably existed before Greek letters were available in web fonts. The ratio of the number of fragments is simply the ratio of two areas.

Comment: Sites like that are a reminder to be grateful for the beautiful MathJax-rendered math on *this* site.

Comment: Thanks a tonne for the reply, you saved a life :)